# Java variable is not initialized

Tags: java, class, if-statement, methods, initialization

I've seen similar questions to this on here and I'm sorry if this seems like a duplicate but the answer to similar questions just didn't help me.
So I have a method thats part of a class. Here it is:

```
public int min_value()
   {
       int min;

       for (int i = 0;i < size - 1;i++)
       {
           min = numbers[i];
           for (int k = 1;k < size; k++)
           {
               if (numbers[k] < min)
               {
                   min = numbers[k];
               }
               else
               {
                   min = numbers[i];
               }
           }
       }

       return min;
   }
```

The error says the variable min might not have been initialized. I can't understand how this can be true. I feel like there's no way the variable wouldn't be initialized out of the for loops. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: imagine `size` is -56

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how the `min_value()` method seems like to the compiler :

```
public int min_value()
{
    int min;

    // for blocks

    return min;
}
```

the **WHY** part: Imagine if size was equal to 1 : The for loops' code blocks will never be executed. Since you are manipulating the `min` variable in  the `for` **blocks** (loops), the compiler assumes that the execution flow **may not enter** these loops, therefore it assumes that this variable *may not be* **initialized**. This wouldn't have been a problem if you were setting `min` as a member variable of a **class** (Since member variables are set to their **default type values** by the compiler), but this is not the case here. (*A method body*)

Comment: great answer. thanks for the clear and in depth explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Change `int min;` to `int min = 0;`

And you will have min initialized.

Edit:

The error is coming from the fact that if `size = 1`, your for loop will never be executed, hence min will never have a value. You cannot return an uninitialized value, that's why you got the error.

Answer (score 1):

If size is 1 or less, min will not be initialised!

Answer (score 1):

Well, in case that i is not smaller then `size - 1` you will return min as is. 
Min has not been initialized in this case and you will return it, that where the error came from.

Just put:
`int min = 0` in the start, it'll be ok. 
In addition, you can do:

```
min = numbers[0]
```